# Onsen Tabbar not updating correctly after state change in one tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, onsen-ui2

Below is a simple example of a Tabbar with three tabs. On the second one, I use a state variable to switch between two components when rendering.
If I browse between the three tabs, everything looks ok. But once I switch the components in tab number two (by first clicking the floating button, and then the Back button), the tabbar does not work correctly. If I do this and go back to Page 1 it looks as it navigates to Page 1, but it still shows the content of Page 2. If I switch and go to Page 3 though, it works fine.
Also, If I do the switch in Page 2, go to Page 1 and then click a little back and forth between the pages it starts working again.

It seems it starts working when I go from one page to a page with a higher index (that's why it's working when going directly to Page 3).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Onsen UI?

Here is the sample code (I am using Meteor, React and Onsen UI):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'onsenui/css/onsenui.css';
import 'onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css';
import ons from 'onsenui';
import {Page,Tabbar, Tab,Toolbar, Fab, BackButton, Icon} from 'react-onsenui';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {index: 0};
  }

  renderTabs() {
    return [
      {
        content: <Page1 key="t1"/>,
        tab: <Tab label='Page1' key="b1" />
      },
      {
        content: <Page2 key="t2"/>,
        tab: <Tab label='Page 2' key="b2" />
      },
      {
        content: <Page3 key="t3"/>,
        tab: <Tab label='Page 3' key="b3" />
      }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Tabbar
        index={this.state.index}
        onPreChange={(event) =>
          {
            if (event.index != this.state.index) {
              this.setState({index: event.index});
            }
          }
        }
        renderTabs={() => this.renderTabs()}
        />
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Page>
        <div>Page 1</div>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { showTest: false};
  }

  showTest(show) {
    this.setState({showTest: show});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.showTest ?
      <Show2 showTest={(show) =>this.showTest(show)} />
      :
      <Show1 showTest={(show) =>this.showTest(show)} />
    );
  }
}

class Show1 extends Component {
  renderToolbar() {
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <div className='center'>Show 1</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  }
  renderFixed() {
    return(
      <Fab position="bottom right" onClick={() => this.props.showTest(true)}><Icon icon='md-plus'/></Fab>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Page renderToolbar={this.renderToolbar} renderFixed={() => this.renderFixed()}>Show 1</Page>
    );
  }
}

class Show2 extends Component {
  renderToolbar() {
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <div className='left'><BackButton onClick={() => this.props.showTest(false)}>Back</BackButton></div>
        <div className='center'>Show 2</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Page renderToolbar={() => this.renderToolbar()}>Show 2</Page>
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Page>
        <div>Page 3</div>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO what you did is fine. Probably it was a bug long ago.

Using *OnsenUI 2.10.10* and *React 16.4.2* your code seems working now. Works well when I go back and forth between the pages, when I change the state on Page2 and even when I use the back button.